# How to use sweetify in Django

Tags: django, django-models, sweetalert

After the teacher login their account he/she can  update the studentbehavior, and after the teacher update studentbehavior of his student the popup message will appear (sweetify message)

scenario:

[image]

this is I want result

[image]

this is my reference: https://github.com/Atrox/sweetify-django

```
def Updatestudentbehavior(request):
    ...
    sweetify.success(request, 'You did it', text='Good job! You successfully showed a SweetAlert message',
                     persistent='Hell yeah')

    **#update data without refreshing page and popup message will appear**


def teacher(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        raise Http404('Only POSTs are allowed')
    try:
         ......
         return render(request, 'Homepage/index.html')
    except EmployeeUser.DoesNotExist:
        messages.warning(request, 'Your Username and password are Incorrect.')
        ….
    return render(request, 'Homepage/TeacherLogin.html')

def corevalues(request):
    ...
    if StudentsBehaviorGrades.objects.filter(Teacher = teacher).exists():

        ….

        return render(request, 'Homepage/updatebehavior.html',
                      {'studentsbehaviorgrade':studentsbehaviorgrade,'student':student,'teacher': teacher, 'behavior': behavior, 'behaviorperlevel': behaviorperlevel,
                       "behaviorperlevels": behaviorperlevels, "period": period})
    else:
        ….
        return render(request, 'Homepage/behavior.html',
                      {'teacher': teacher, 'behavior': behavior, 'behaviorperlevel': behaviorperlevel,
                       "behaviorperlevels": behaviorperlevels, "Students": Students, "period": period})
```

urls.py

```
path('teacher/', Homepage.views.teacher, name='teacher'),
path('Updatestudentbehavior/', Homepage.views.Updatestudentbehavior, name='Updatestudentbehavior'),
```

my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ….
    'sweetify',
]

SWEETIFY_SWEETALERT_LIBRARY = 'sweetalert2'
```

my html

```
{% load sweetify %}
{% sweetify %}
….
<form class="myform" action="{% url 'Updatestudentbehavior' %}" method="POST"  style="width: 100%" >{% csrf_token %}
    ….
    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="myform">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).on('submit', '.myform', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(this);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'{% url 'Updatestudentbehavior' %}'
            data:{
                teacher:$('#teacher').val(),
                student:$('#student').val(),
                marking:$('#marking').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success:function(){
                alert('Update Success');
            }
        });
   });
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

when i try this

```
def Updatestudentbehavior(request):
     ….
     sweetify.success(request, 'You did it', text='Good job! You successfully showed a SweetAlert message',
                 persistent='Hell yeah')
     return redirect(request.path_info)
```

this is the error i get

[image]

and this is from terminal

[image]

Answer (score 2):

check your console , you will find an error that Swal is not defined.

For making sweetify working you have to add the sweetalert2 cdn :
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9
put the this link in the src of the script tags in your base/layout template.

I think I have tried to answer your question, if there is any other question you may ask. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is pretty clear. The page has been redirected too many times. It is happening because you have used `return redirect(request.path_info)` in the `Updatestudentbehavior` view.

If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path_info), you will notice that `request.path_info` is the url of the current view itself. It means that the view it redirecting the request to itself again and again leading to the error in browser.

Instead of using `request.path_info`, please use the url of the page from which this request was generated.

Comment: @Mary does this answer your question?

Comment: How do I connect it with sweetify? since my question is about on how to use sweetify @AKS

Comment: If someone is downvoting the answer, It will be helpful if they also provide a reason for that. That will result in a good learning for me.